# Can't get featureLayer.setStyle to remove highlight on mouseout (mapbox/leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

So, I'm building a map of water taking permits in Toronto. Work in progress available here: http://pennybeames.net/maps/PermitsTO.html

I'm using L.mapbox.featureLayer to add my markers:

```
var permitsLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(permits,  {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, permitsStyle(feature));}
     }).addTo(map);
```

I've got the custom info control from the Leaflet choropleth example working (http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html).

I change the style and update the info in the custom control as follows:

```
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        layer.on('mousemove', function (e) {
            // highlight feature
                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9
                });

                //update properties in DomUtil
                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
        });
   });
```

All is working smoothly until we get to mouseout. The info control updates fine (either switching to the properties of the new target or reverting to its empty state), but the style won't change. The highlight stays on.

```
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                  //reset style
                  featureLayer.setStyle(permitsStyle);

                  //empty properties in DomUtil
                  info.update();
         });
   });
```

I don't get any errors, but I also don't see any change. I've tried

```
featureLayer.resetStyle(e.target)
```

but then all I get is Uncaught TypeError: featureLayer.resetStyle is not a function.

There is probably a really simple question, but it's eluding me. Insight, hivemind?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind to your events inside the `eachLayer` loop, just do `featureLayer.on('myevent',function(e) {e.layer.setStyle(MY_NEW_STYLE)})`

Comment: Just gave this a go with the same result. No error, but the new style still won't set... Hermmm...

Comment: Can you update your test page with your new code(pennybeames.net/maps/PermitsTO.html)? Secondly, in your `mouseout` you are referencing a function but calling it like a plain old variable.And you forgot the parameter it needs. You should be using `featureLayer.setStyle(permitsStyle(e.layer));`

Comment: I've updated the code to include your suggestion. I've also tinkered with bringToFront and bringToBack. I don't know enough to understand why these two methods will work but setStyle won't...

Comment: Are you sure you updated that page?You are still binding events inside `eachLayer` loops. And you are binding events to `mouseout` in two different locations - Consolidate the first into the `featureLayer.on('mouseout',function(e) {` block.